# How can I keep the spacing in this Javascript regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g
```

Right now it trims off the space. But I want to keep the space. (I just want to remove the symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the space character.

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g
```

Comment: How come this doesn't remove the hashtag (#) sign?

Comment: var s = '#fashion'; s = s.replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g', '');

Comment: @TIMEX, don't quote the regex, then it is working `s = s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g, '');`

Answer (score 5):

This

```
[A-Za-z0-9]
```

is a **[character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)**. It will match any character that is listed inside that class.

If you put a `^` as starting character inside the class

```
[^A-Za-z0-9]
```

it is a **negated character class**. It will match any character that is **NOT** listed inside that class.

So if you don't want the space to be matched, just add it to the class:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9 ]
```

If you want to keep all **whitespace** (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) you can use the shorthand character class `\s`

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
var s = '#fashion!?;Foobar,.;:'; 
s = s.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/g, ''); 
alert(s);
```

puts

> fashionFoobar

My Blog post: [What absolutely every Programmer should know about regular expressions](http://blog.xisb.de/?p=4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
/[^\sA-Za-z0-9]/g
```